# LastWriteTime of a shared file in Powershell

Tags: powershell, time

I would like to get the last write time of a txt file which is located in a shared folder. I write the last write time in an other file. The problem is that I'm always getting an odd DateTime ("Sunday, December 31, 1600 4:00:00 PM"). I found this description in the MSDN : "If the file described in the FileSystemInfo object does not exist, this property will return 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), adjusted to local time."
To check whether I can access from the file I loaded something out of this file and it works. Therefore my file exists. If I apply my program on a local drive I'm getting right dates. The following code represent my program:

```
$SharedFolder = "\\SharedFolder"


new-psdrive -name Z -psprovider FileSystem -root $SharedFolder
$usersFileName = "Z:\users.txt"
$file = New-object System.IO.FileInfo $usersFileName
$tempDate = $file.LastWriteTime


while($true){

        $file2 = New-object System.IO.FileInfo $usersFileName       
                $tempDate2 = $file2.LastWriteTime

        if($tempDate -ne $tempDate2)

                {
            $name ="ahs been changed"
            $Name | out-file C:\users\test\desktop\test2.txt -append
            $file = New-object System.IO.FileInfo $usersFileName
                        $tempDate = $file.LastWriteTime
                }
        $tempDate | out-file C:\users\test\desktop\test2.txt -append
        Start-sleep -s 2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
$file = New-object System.IO.FileInfo $usersFileName
```

You can just do

```
$file = get-item $usersFileName
```

Then you can still do `$file.LastWriteTime` and get the proper time.

I think creating a `FileInfo` object by yourself doesn't work because the PsDrive might not be known to the .Net method, and eventhough that is what `Get-Item` returns, it is able to handle it internally.  Note that creating the object by yourself with the share path, does give right time, so it is not an issue with share, but with the PsDrive.

Also, you need not create objects again and again and then check on the FileInfo. You can just call the `Refresh` method. This is the same with `Get-Item`. You can just call `Refresh` to get the updated times.

And btw, you seem to be watching modifications to a file and logging it. .Net and Powershell ( through eventing etc.) have great support for doing such things. Have a look at FileSystemWatcher ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx )

Comment: I know the FileSystemWatcher. The Problem was that it throws at least two events if my file changed. In my case that is a problem which could not be easily handled. But your solution with get-item just works fine. Thank you for that. If you have a hint to resolve the event-handling problem with FileSystemWatcher would be nice.

Comment: @seven-ply - Raise what you did with FileSytemWatcher etc. in a different question and am sure someone will be able to help you.